# Raster to polygon conversion's raster field takes only "Value"

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, convert, raster-conversion

Recently I am working with raster data and arcobjects.net. Here I find something new for me. And here some question arises in my mind. I tried to search some document that can satisfy my mind, but I couldn't find. Any pointer or document or link would be helpful.

When I perform *[Raster to polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000008000000)* conversion's, fourth parameter is raster_field. Sometimes I can give either "Value" field or "Count" field in it, sometimes, its only "Value" field. when and why? When does it take only "Value" field?

Answer (score 2):

Would that be any help for you- [Raster dataset attribute tables](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000009000000)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calculate Geometry if I got your problem correctly.

1. Add a new Field (while Editor Closed)>
2. Start The Editor
3. Right click on field Name
4. click Field Calculator

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  You mention "Calculate Geometry" at the start but then in your steps you say to click "Field Calculator" - for me these are two separate functions, can you confirm which one to use?  Also what steps to follow after step 4?